# Taking less than a minute to solve a problem within 10% which was stated in less than 10 seconds?

Tags: mathematics, physics

I believe there is a story about a 20th century sciencist (either Neumann or Feynmann I think) who, at some dinner or some sort of gathering, made the following claim to his fellow colleagues: He asserted that in less than 1 minute he can find the answer (with 10% error) of any mathematical problem which could be stated in less than 10 seconds (I'm not 100% sure if I got the parameters exactly right). Is there any source of this story?

The way I remember coming across the story is in a youtube video, where the author mentioned that the collegues should've asked for the value of $\tan(10^{1000})$, which would've required the sciencist to know $\pi$ to very many decimal places.

Comment: Feynman. He's told this story multiple times.